# CSS can't set background-image to none in child element

Tags: css, background-image

I've set background-image property in parent element as:

[image]

[Full screenshot](http://kagda.ru/i/340199634519_15-04-2015-17:30:59_3401.png)

It works fine.

Inside parent element what has  id set as "content" I have a child element 
with id "comments".

[image]

[Full screenshot](http://kagda.ru/i/d1011365d1707_15-04-2015-17:24:16_d101.png)

Whatever I have tried it doesn't take any effect. I tried to set it to none or even to change to another image. Nothing helps.  I want to remove background image for child element or to change it.

Please help, I can't find where  I did a foolish thing this time(

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Comment: add a transparent background ?   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);

Comment: there is a lot of code. I use sass.  I don't think it can be useful. I can give a link to website, but I fear it will be understood as an attempt to promote it. should I ?

Comment: No. Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to add a `clearfix` class for the child element?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you are trying to "cut a hole" in the parent's background it's not really possible quite yet. Depends on the effect you are after.

Comment: Your parent and comments have same background looking at the screenshots. You will need to give comments a solid white background as background:none will still show parents background.

Comment: The background image or color of the parent container will be visible under the child element unless you set some other background image or color to the child element.  That is how CSS paints the various layers of the elements on a page.

Comment: @anpsmn Unless the child element has a parent with a background that is not #content ://

Comment: @AlexShulzhenko add some code including `#content` div and its child `#comments` in addition to their related styles in a fiddle. Unless you'll get only speculative answers.

Comment: ok, that's all fine. I went to read docs. bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , if you want the child element not to have a background you can add

```
#comment{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

and try to remove any other background properties for this element that may be overriding

If you need a different background for the child element then add the follwing

```
#comment{
background:url(../path/to/image);
background-position:center;
background-size:cover
}
```

if you want to maintain the image aspect ratio then change `cover` to `contain` but this may not fill the whole #comments div in order to respect the ratio

If you need to add a pattern background then use `background-repeat:repeat` and remove `cover`  and `center`

Comment: unfortunately still the same(

Comment: If he put a `transparent` or `none` background, the parent's background will still visible on the child.

Comment: @FaresM. I believe that is what the OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @AwRak according to the included screenshot, @AlexShulzhenko wants a different background for the child div `#comment`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want with the current way that your HTML is structured. The `#comments` div is a child element of the `#content` div, which has a background set. Even if you give `#comments` no background, it's still going to show the background of the parent element. Perhaps you could just make the background of `#comments` white to overlay on top of the `#content` div? Or remove `#comments` from the parent element.

Example CSS:

```
#comments {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either move the `comments` box out of the `content` element, so `content's background` does not cover `comments`, or give the comments element its own `background` (color or image).

From your screenshots it seems everything is fine. Technically, all DOM elements are transparent by default, and it has no background, it is transparent. So your comments are transparent and have no background. So by setting it to none you are not chanding anything, because its `background` is none.